# How can i align a icon vertically, when using it in a richText flutter

Tags: flutter

i am trying to create a simple gesture detector, with some text, and an icon in the start, but i seem to hit a wall when trying to center the icon (yes a row have been tried, but i need something where the width does not go beyond the content withing), here is what i have so far:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() {
                      playerNames.remove(name);
                    }),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.clear,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                      ),
                    ),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        name,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.021,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.71)),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                )),
          )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try **InlineSpan** inside TextSpan

```
       TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black), 
            children: <InlineSpan>[ 
              TextSpan(text: 'hello'), 
              WidgetSpan( 
                alignment: ui.PlaceholderAlignment.middle, 
                child: Text( 'Jack', 
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white), 
                ), 
              ), 
              TextSpan(text: ' doctor'), 
            ] 
        ),
```

Comment: who is this ui ? used on alignment I had an issue there

Comment: There is library dart:ui, a imported it as ui
In nutshell, import "dart:ui" as ui

Comment: or like most people do, just remove the "ui." and just write PlaceholderAlignment.middle